# Error Code: 2250 when deleting an invoice

Tags: quickbooks-online

QBO raises the error code 2250 "You must fill out at least one split line". Why does it need to pass a line for deleting an invoice? Should it just require invoice.id?

Comment: Please add some more details about your problem, so that we can get the whole picture here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever bizarre reason, the Intuit v3 "delete" call requires that you pass *the entire invoice object* to the delete call in order to delete an invoice.

It's weird, yes. Unfortunately, it's also the way the API works and is required.

You can see this documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/060_delete

Quoting:

> The request body includes the **full payload of the object as returned in a read response**.

Comment: Weird doesn't begin to cover it, and the error message body doesn't help either. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a hack way without submitting the entire object. It accepts an empty line and sync token along with the invoice id.

Comment: care to share the hack?